# How to highlight link to a page that the user is currently on in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a sidebar with several links (all dynamically generated by the user - similar to creating notes and then having a link to those notes):

[image]

The 'Add stage' button allows them to add a new note.

The component used to generate this list a v-navigation-drawer:

```
    <v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-expansion-panels>
            <v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel-content>
                    <v-list 
                        v-for="(note, i) in notes"
                        :key="i"
                    >
                        <v-card flat @click="getNoteURL(note)">
                            <div class="d-flex pt-2" v-else>
                                <v-icon>
                                    {{ note.mdi_name }}
                                </v-icon>
                                <p>{{ note.name }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-list>
                </v-expansion-panel-content>
            </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-expansion-panels>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

getNoteURL is a method which takes the user where the url is .../notes/5

```
    getNoteURL(note) {
        window.location.href = window.routes['notes.show'].replace('{note}', note.id);
    },
```

How would I be able to highlight the specific links such that whichever page the user is on, the link darkens in colour? For example like so:

[image]

Comment: You should use `vue-router` and therefore using `vue-link` that will allow your SPA to move to a specific path. If the link in the sidebar are matching the sidebar's link paths, they will highlight by themselves or at least have a specific class tied to them. It will be this class: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact-path-active-class PS: `window.location` is **not** a solution in an SPA.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<router-link>` and set active class on each route are you in.
like this:

```
<router-link
  v-for="(note, i) in notes"
  :key="i"
  :to="note"
  :active-class="customActive"
>
  {{ note }}
</router-link>
```

and create `.customActive` class for active route